# Pandas round to the nearest "n"

Tags: python, pandas

Numeric series have a nice rounding method for rounding to powers of ten, eg

```
>>> pd.Series([11,16,21]).round(-1)
0    10
1    20
2    20
dtype: int64
```

Is there an equivalently nice syntax for rounding to the nearest 5 (or other non-power of 10)? I'm sort of wishing that `round` could take non-integer values?

Answer (score 38):

You can utilize a custom rounding function and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) it to your series.

```
import pandas as pd

def custom_round(x, base=5):
    return int(base * round(float(x)/base))

df = pd.Series([11,16,21]).apply(lambda x: custom_round(x, base=5))
```

Now you just need to adjust the `base` to get to the nearest value you want.

A couple examples:

#### Base = 5:

```
0    10
1    15
2    20
dtype: int64
```

#### Base = 7

```
0    14
1    14
2    21
dtype: int64
```

#### Base = 3

```
0    12
1    15
2    21
dtype: int64
```

---

Your goal of non-integer values can be done too.

```
def custom_round(x, base=5):
    return base * round(float(x)/base)

df = pd.Series([11.35,16.91,21.12]).apply(lambda x: custom_round(x, base=.05))
```

By rounding to the nearest 0.05, you'll get these results (notice I modified your series slightly for this example):

```
0    11.35
1    16.90
2    21.10
dtype: float64
```

If you keep your original series of integers, this `apply` will change your series into `float` values:

Comment: This doesn't show the second digit when the float ends in a zero e.g 0.6 How can I make it that it shows 0.60 instead?  `df['B'] = "A = "  + df['C'].astype(str)` This happen when I try to make the column as an string

Answer (score 15):

One of the answers suggests using `apply` to pass a `lambda` which divides by 10, rounds it to nearest integer, and then multiplies by 10. Instead, you can take advantage of vectorisation in `pandas` by doing the following:

```py
>>> s = pd.Series([11, 16, 21])
>>> (s / 10).round().astype(int) * 10
0    10
1    20
2    20
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This should be voted higher; `apply` is very inefficient, especially when iterating over the index of large DataFrames (it is somewhat acceptable if running over the columns as those are usually fewer).

Answer (score 3):

I guess I could do this:

```
def round_down_to_nearest(self, n):
    return (self // n) * n

pd.Series.round_down_to_nearest = round_down_to_nearest
```

Comment: This is round-down, not round-to-nearest (19 will become 15 instead of 20).

Comment: @kennytm good point ... i'll rename the function (since this is actually what I wanted)

Answer (score 0):

I think some the above suggestions wont work when series contains a number 1 or less. here is an improved answer.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Example DataFrame
data = {'A': [1.1, 22, 48, 17], 'B': [41, 18, 0.3, 99]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Round up to the nearest 10th
df_rounded = np.ceil(df / 10.0) * 10

print(df_rounded)
```