# Pandas custom rounding given a list of values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a clever, straightforward way to round a column of integer data given some set of values. Here is my example data

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series([11,16,21, 125])
```

Say I want to round up to to the nearest custom list of values using an undefined function called `custom_round`. Such that when a rounding is applied, each value in the original series is rounded up to the nearest value, or if the are already larger than the maximum, they are brought down to that maximum.

```
rounding_logic = pd.Series([15, 20, 100])

df = pd.Series([11,16,21]).apply(lambda x: custom_round(x, round_list=rounding_logic))
```

Afterwards df is now `pd.Series([15, 20, 100, 100])`.

I can think of some horribly inefficient and ugly if else statements, but I suspect there must be a far easier approach. I have seen custom rounding answers where the objective is to round to the nearest n, given some base number e.g. [Pandas round to the nearest "n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372030/pandas-round-to-the-nearest-n) but nothing that solves my particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df = pd.Series([11,16,21, 125])

rounding_logic = pd.Series([15, 20, 100])
labels = rounding_logic.tolist()
rounding_logic = pd.Series([-np.inf]).append(rounding_logic) # add infinity as leftmost edge

pd.cut(df, rounding_logic, labels=labels).fillna(rounding_logic.iloc[-1])
# get bins, assign labels and fill all values that greater than 100 with 100
```

Output:

```
0     15
1     20
2    100
3    100
dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [15 < 20 < 100]
```

Comment: Neat, but note that the back and forth between pd.Series and list of rounding_logic - labels (at least the first two lines) is not necessary, just simply have labels = [15, 20, 100]

Answer (score 1):

it still has to be a bit messy, because of "if its larger than maximum" case:

```
def custom_round(col, rounding_vals = np.array([15, 20, 100])):
    if isinstance(col, pd.Series):
        col = col.to_numpy()
    return rounding_vals[np.argmax(np.concatenate([col[:, None] < rounding_vals[None, :-1], np.ones((len(col), 1), dtype=bool)], axis=1), axis=1)]
```