# How to group one column biassed on various intervals from another in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pd.DataFrame:

```
source = pd.DataFrame([[0.99, 0.98, 0.93, 0.81, 0.85, 0.71, 0.7, 0.69, 0.68, 0.66], 
              [100, 12, 312, 23, 2, 12, 32, 21, 21, 21]]).T
```

I would like to convert it as quickly as possible to:

```
desired_result = pd.DataFrame([[0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6], [424, 25, 44, 63]]).T
```

Where above I define an interval of `0.1` which I apply to column `0` to the `source` dataframe and sum the `1` column of the same dataframe. The idea is that this should work with different intervals.

What I tried:

1. I thought about using `pd.cut` but that does not seem to be what I am looking for.
2. I know that if I add a new column to `source` which is with duplicated values of 0.9, 0.8, 0.7 and 0.6 on the corresponding rows then I can use `groupby` on this new column and then `sum`, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner and quicker way to do this? e.g. smth like this:

```
interval = 0.1
source['ints'] = (source[0] / interval).astype(int)
result = source.groupby(source['ints']).sum().reset_index()
result
```

However the above would not work if I were to change the interval form 0.1 to 0.05 for example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For speed: always try to vectorize all you can, and *avoid* `apply` as much as possible.

Here is a faster way (credit to @DavidErickson for `sort=False`):

```
interval = 0.1
source.groupby(np.trunc(source[0] / interval) * interval, sort=False)[1].sum().reset_index()
# out:
     0      1
0  0.9  424.0
1  0.8   25.0
2  0.7   12.0
3  0.6   95.0
```

The speed difference can be quite dramatic for large `df`.

Try with 1 million rows, grouped in 10K bins:

```
source = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(scale=1000, size=(int(1e6), 2)))

%%timeit
# ... (as above)
26.7 ms ± 292 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

With an `apply` instead:

```
1.51 s ± 11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

(50x slower).

Comment: It looks like you have a quick computer (my computer is 3x slower than yours). Anyway, on my computer my solution is about 10% faster. Also, passing `sort=False` to the groupby should speed up your code about 5%.

Comment: @DavidErickson: good idea to use `sort=False`.

Comment: it's not _my_ computer, I just rent it... A run of the mill `r5d.2xlarge` AWS instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `custom_round` function that I made 3 modifications from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40372261/6366770:

1. I used `np.floor` instead of `round` as you want to go down.
2. This messes up values that are on the "border" of a bin, so I add `+ base/100` (so `0.9` would be `0.9 + .009 = 0.909` and round down to .9 instead of incorrectly to 0.8), so that it is just above the border and rounds down correctly. I think this will cover you. You can do `1 / 1000` to be safe.
3. The answer I share was looking for `int`, so  removed `int`, as we are looking at rounding floats

---

```
source = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(scale=1000, size=(int(1e6), 2)))

def custom_round(x, y, base):
    return source.groupby((base * np.floor((x + (base / 100)) / base)), sort=False)[y].sum()


%timeit custom_round(source[0], 1, .1)
89.8 ms ± 1.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

On my computer, the accepted answer is slower:

```
102 ms ± 1.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks. But then if I define different intervals, it would not work on each on, right?

Comment: True, this would only work on interval of 0.1

Comment: I probably phrased my question wrong (which is my bad). I edited it now a bit for clarity.

Comment: @Newskooler I have made it more dynamic

Comment: This works. .apply is one way to go for sure. Thanks.

Comment: @Newskooler I've change my code to not be apply for speed.